# Selector for the first element with Jquery

Tags: jquery, selector, submenu, css-selectors

I have a menu structure like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="">Parent menu</a> <--------------
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Parent menu</a> <--------------
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need a selector for the Parent menu anchor element. $('li a:first') is not good, because its select the first child link too. I have no other idea.

Comment: Doesn't `$('li a:first')[0]` work?

Comment: I tried that without any luck.

Comment: I figured it out.

    $('ul ul').parent().children(':first-child'), just i can't answer my question yet:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
$('ul ul').parent().children(':first-child')
```

Answer (score 1):

just see...

```
<ul id="temp">
        <li>
            <a href="1">Parent menu1</a> <--------------
            <ul>
                <li><a href="2"></a></li>
                <li><a href="3"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="4">Parent menu2</a> <--------------
            <ul>
                <li><a href="5"></a></li>
                <li><a href="6"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

<SCRIPT>

    //alert("++++++++++++"+$('#temp').children('li').length+"++++++++++++");
    $('#temp').children('li').each(function(index){
        index   =   parseInt(index)+1;
        console.log('----------->'+$('#temp li:nth-child('+ index +')').has('ul').children('a').html());
    });
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i found a better solution:  $('ul ul').parent().children(':first-child') I just can't answer my question yet.